# OpenCL Cloo Null referenece exception when compiling kernel

Tags: c#, .net, opencl, cloo

I'm trying to compile a program to run some opencl code using Cloo.

```
static void Main(string[] arg)
{
    CLCalc.InitCL();
    string src = File.ReadAllText("kernels.cl");   

    CLCalc.Program.Compile(src);
}
```

The program was previously working fine, but now I get a null reference exception.
[image: error]
At first I thought there was a bug in my opencl code but I replaced the opencl with a very simple kernel and it still would not compile.

ie:

```
static void Main(string[] arg)
{
    CLCalc.InitCL();
    //string src = File.ReadAllText("kernels.cl");   
    string src = "__kernel void hello(__global char * out){}";

    CLCalc.Program.Compile(src);
}
```

[image: NoDevice]

Note that there is no device present. Why would this be? I have a GPU...

This has been a problem since installing the [CUDA tooklkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) on my PC. Is it even possible for this to be the cause though?

**EDIT**

I've created a very simple project with only a few lines of code which exbits my bug.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using OpenCL;
using OpenCL.Net;
using OpenCLTemplate;

namespace ClooTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CLCalc.InitCL();

            string src = "__kernel void hello(__global char * out){}";

            CLCalc.Program.Compile(src);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've recoverd an old working copy of my program from USB. It ran fine on my home PC. But I get the same bug when I run it on my work PC.

[image: cmd]

**EDIT**

If I put a break point in before the compile line I can see an exception
[image: NotFound]

Why would it not be finding my device all of a sudden?

**EDIT**

When I look at my OpenCL devices the only one listed as default device is my CPU ...

[image: Devices]

Why!?

Comment: I should note that I'm using the implementation of opencl found here
http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=13&Itemid=66

Comment: http://www.cmsoft.com.br/download/OpenCLTemplate.zip

Comment: I've just found a backup of an old working version of my program from a USB. It is now exhibiting the same bug! I'm starting to think its time to give ghost busters a call...

Comment: I should also add the the program dies at the line 
CLCalc.Program.Compile(src);

Comment: It has been suggested to me that the problem may be related to the NVIDIA driver. I've tried installing the latest driver for my graphics card (Quadro K4000) http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/75456/en-us

Still no success

Comment: It appears my CPU actually supports a later version of OpenCL than my GPU. But of course my GPU is still the better option. I wonder if since downloading the latest drivers, my default OpenCL device has been my CPU since it has the latest version.

Comment: Can you please post what code do you run under InitCL()? Is not possible that the CL devices disappear after you install another platform. My guess is that you are just using a different ICD driver (32bit / 64bits), or that you are searching inside the platform 0 only, and that platform is not the correct one any more.

Comment: InitCL is a cloo function, its not mine.

Comment: Sry, not very familiar with Cloo. 
My impresion is that the ICD loader is a diferent one, you can try compiling your app in 32bits/64bits. Depending on that the app may use one loader or the other, and see some devices only.

Comment: @DarkZeros This is a very good idea. I've been using the express version of visual studio which does not support 64bit. However I've just tried moving this to a different PC (64 bit) and the program works! I'm not sure if the processor architecture issue is what caused the problem.

Comment: Also interesting to note that my home PC is 64 bit