# Cant get my graphics card device in opencl

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I am trying to write a simple opencl program and I'm not able to get my Graphics card it seems.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CL/cl.h"

#define DATA_SIZE 10

const char *KernelSource = 
"__kernel void hello(__global float * input, __global float *output)\n"\
"{\n"\
" size_t id = get_global_id(0);\n"\
" output[id] = input[id] * input[id]; \n"\
"}\n"\
"\n";
int main()
{
    cl_context context;
    cl_context_properties properties[3];
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_command_queue command_queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_int err;
    cl_uint num_of_platforms=0;
    cl_platform_id platform_id;
    cl_platform_id * platform_ids;
    cl_device_id device_id;
    cl_uint num_of_devices=0;
    cl_mem input, output;
    size_t global;

    float inputData[DATA_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    float results[DATA_SIZE] = {0};

    int i;

    if (clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &num_of_platforms) != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Unable to get platform_id\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &num_of_devices) != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Unable to get device_id\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints `Unable to get device_id`

When I put in a break point and inspect `num_of_platforms`. It seems that I have 3 platforms.

I have an intel CPU and an NVIDIA GPU (quadro K4000)

However, it says I have 0 devices of type `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`

I can see in my device manager I have my GPU visible

[image: K4000]

I think this might be related to [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005511/opencl-cloo-null-referenece-exception-when-compiling-kernel) I'm having using cloo on the same PC.

It also appears that the only listed opencl device is my CPU

[image: ClooCPU]

The Opencl version supported by my CPU (1.2) is actuall later than the GPU (1.1).

I'm not sure about how to go about debugging this any further ...

Comment: Have you installed the correct drivers? You might be running the default Windows drivers which gives you a display device and not much else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to get GPU device from the first platform. How do you know it has to be on the first platform? You should try all the platforms.

```
if (clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_of_platforms) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Unable to get platform_id\n");
    return 1;
}
cl_platform_id *platform_ids = new cl_platform_id[num_of_platforms];
if (clGetPlatformIDs(num_of_platforms, &platform_ids, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Unable to get platform_id\n");
    return 1;
}
bool found = false;
for(int i=0; i<num_of_platforms; i++)
    if(clGetDeviceIDs(&platform_id[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &num_of_devices) == CL_SUCCESS){
         found = true;
         break;
    }
if(!found){
    printf("Unable to get device_id\n");
    return 1;
}
```